# Depleted Honda Fit battery -- how long to recharge, how to re-enable radio?

Tags: honda, battery, battery-drain, fit

I left the interior map lights (driver & passenger side lights) on for about 30 hours, depleting the batter in my Honda Fit. I could barely see the lights on.  Fortunately, at least one towing service had a service vehicle that could get into the underground where it was parked.  After getting boosted, I drove it around with high RPMs, mostly on the highway, for about an hour, interspersed with normal city RPMs for errands (though I tried to keep the RPMs high even then).

(1) How long does it take for a typical OEM sub-compact battery to be charged?  There is a color indicator that shows when the batter is in good shape, when it needs fluid, and when it needs charging.  After the total of about 1 hour of high RPMs, the color indicator still says the battery needs charging. [This post](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3307/rpm-and-duration-to-recharge-a-battery) mentions 2 to 5 hours, wondering if this ballpark range can be narrowed for a Honda Fit.

(2) The combined audio/clock system got reset, as evidenced by the nonsensical time on the clock.  When I turned on the radio, it asked to enter a code.  A quick browse through the audio and battery changing sections of the manual reveals nothing about a code.  What is this code?

Answer (score 1):

I would proceed as follows:

1 I would charge the battery using a good battery charger overnight. Either while it is still on the car or removed and taken into the house (code is not an issue... as you have already lost it).

2 The radio code is usually on a separate card or even a little "tab" on the key ring, once you have it then just enter it. If you cannot find it, then you probably need to go to the dealer and they can sort it - sometimes free, sometimes not.

Comment: If I had a larger place, I would buy a battery charger, but right now, I have no place to store anything new.  So while the battery charger is a better solution in general, the option isn't available to me.  I will have to rely on my daily commute (20 min city streets, 10 min highway, each way) to charge the battery, along with whatever aimless driving I can do.  I'll try to keep the RPMs high, but from my cited post, high RPMs don't seem to matter.  Thanks for the hint on the audio system code, will try to find it.

Comment: Actually, I mulled the charger a bit more. If it was tiny, it might be feasible for me to get it.  But then I realized that the highrise underground doesn't have outlets.  In fact, this is an issue whenever I want to vacuum the car.  I end up doing that once per year, in a nearby parking lot that does have an outlet.  During the weekend, so that I don't peeve off the businesses there.

Answer (score 0):

:) so for the radio code you can do it yourself without going to the dealership. You just have to get the serial code in the same device.

So, just press the buttons 1 and 6 while you try to turn on the radio at the same time and the serial number must appear. Then you can go to the website  of Honda. https://radio-navicode.honda.com/ and they can helpo you out for free.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, WandaGz.  I found the slip of paper with the radio code.  But it's handy to have the procedure that you provided for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The battery status indicator finally shows that it is charged, after 3 weeks.  So it can take weeks of typical daily work commutes to recharge a depleted battery on the Fit.

As for the radio code, that is on a piece of paper that forms part of the documentation package when the car was purchased.  However, the other responds' answers show solutions if you no longer have that piece of paper.